# Error reading jobject from jsonreader

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

My JSON string looks like this.

```
{"userid":26,
"Comment":"ok",
"registertime":"2016-11-12T17:02:23.51",
"Value":"[{\"codemeli\":\"11111\"
,\"birthday\":\"Nov 6, 2016 5:21:23 PM\",
\"comment\":\"it is a good file",
\"type\":\"active\"}]"}
```

When I use the Parse method like below I run into an error stated below:

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);
```

> error reading jobject from jsonreader. current jsonreader item is not
>   an object startarray

How do I get rid of this error or is there any other method to parse my json string and fetch the values?

Comment: your json is not in a correct format i believe, however u can use `JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize()` as well then pass it to your model or Entity.

Comment: pls help me i dont know how can it

Comment: see if this article helps you out :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/deserialize-json-with-c-sharp

Comment: u "say my json in not in a correct format"  where is my mistake?

Comment: that's some invalid `json` data

Comment: You can check the validity of your json strings with www.jsoneditoronline.org . erdi yilmaz's string should work. How are getting that string?

Comment: my json have some invalid json data